# AmChart- After updating fieldMappings and dataSet,Graph is not plotting

Tags: amcharts

Problem Statement:

after updating fieldMappings and dataSet during runtime(After clicking on a button) for a stockgraph, validateNow() / validteData() is not plotting the graph.

Note: MACD0 is added from 25th element onward and expoSignalLine0 is added from 33rd element onward in the **dataprovider** and **fieldMapping** is also getting updated and can be verified same in console.`enter code here`

Following is the Code snippet:
(addMACD function is called on click of a button)

```
function addMACD() {
    var chart = AmCharts.charts[ 0 ];
    AmCharts.MACDGraphs = 0;
    AmCharts.expoSignalLineGraphs = 0;
    var MACDField = "MACD"+ AmCharts.MACDGraphs;
    var expoSignalLineField = "expoSignalLine"+ AmCharts.expoSignalLineGraphs;

    chart.dataSets[0].fieldMappings.push( {
            fromField : MACDField,
            toField : MACDField
    },

    {
            fromField : expoSignalLineField,
            toField : expoSignalLineField
    });

     var currClose;
     var prevClose;
     var twelveDayEMA =[];
     var twentySixDayEMA =[];
     var MACDarray = [];
     var signalLineArray = [];
     var MACDperiod = 9 ;// 9 day exponential average
    for ( var i = 1; i < (chart.dataSets[0].dataProvider.length); i++) {

            var dp = chart.dataSets[0].dataProvider[i - 1];
            prevClose = parseFloat(dp["close"]);

            var dp = chart.dataSets[0].dataProvider[i];
            currClose = parseFloat(dp["close"]);
            if( i==1){
                    twelveDayEMA[i] = (0.15*currClose) + (0.85*prevClose);
                    twentySixDayEMA[i] = (0.075*currClose) + (0.925*prevClose);
            }
            else{
                    twelveDayEMA[i] = (0.15*currClose) + (0.85*twelveDayEMA[i - 1]);
                    twentySixDayEMA[i] = (0.075*currClose) + (0.925*twentySixDayEMA[i - 1]);
            }

            if(i >= 25){

                    MACDarray[i] = twelveDayEMA[i] - twentySixDayEMA[i] ;
                    dp[MACDField] = MACDarray[i];

                    if(i == 25){
                            signalLineArray[i] =  MACDarray[i];

                    }
                    else{
                            signalLineArray[i] = ( MACDarray[i]*(2/( MACDperiod + 1)) ) + ( signalLineArray[i - 1]*(1-(2/( MACDperiod + 1))) )        
                    }
            }
            if(i >=33){
                    dp[expoSignalLineField] = signalLineArray[i];
            }

    }
    console.log(chart);


  if ( chart.panels.length == 1 || chart.panels.length == 2 || chart.panels.length == 3 || chart.panels.length == 4 || chart.panels.length == 5) {

var newPanel = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
newPanel.allowTurningOff = true;
newPanel.title = "MACD";
newPanel.showCategoryAxis = false;

graph1 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
graph1.valueField = MACDField;
graph1.useDataSetColors = false;
graph1.lineColor="#6699FF";
graph1.title = "MACD";
newPanel.stockGraphs.push( graph1 );

graph2 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
graph2.valueField =expoSignalLineField;
graph2.useDataSetColors = false;
graph2.lineColor = "#990000";
graph2.title = "MACD2";
newPanel.stockGraphs.push( graph2 );

var legend = new AmCharts.StockLegend();
legend.markerType = "none";
legend.markerSize = 0;
newPanel.stockLegend = legend;
chart.addPanelAt( newPanel, 1 );



 chart.validateData();
 chart.validateNow();
 //chart.write("chartdiv");
  }
 }
```

Comment: here is the fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/ujat2zar/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `validateNow` first, then call `validateData`.

Alternatively, you can call [`validateNow(true, false)`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#validateNow) which has the same effect as calling the two functions separately.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujat2zar/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much.